# Entity Framework code-first + WCF DataService - can't make it work

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, wcf-data-services

When I try to ask a service - I get an exception

> Unable to load metadata for return type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Inet says that service can not find model files. But I use code-first, and have no such files.

I use `Microsoft.Data.Services`.

You can say that my connection string is wrong.

But when I try to init `myDbContext`, my database is created without tables.

No breakpoints after creation context have been hit.

What can I do???

Comment: Posting some code would help.  Also, any error messages and stack traces you are getting.

Comment: is your return type part of your EF code first model, context?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing datamember attributes in fields and datacontract attribute in class.

It is best to have some light class between your db and wcf ,so that you can add special attributes or create complex entities to use in wcf endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Just info if you are missing something about EF Code First & WCF Data Service.

> There are two assemblies for creating and consuming WCF Data Services
>   in the .NET Framework 4: **System.Data.Services.dll** and
>   **System.Data.Services.Client.dll**. If you try to use these with a
>   DbContext and Code First classes, they won’t work out of the box. The
>   issue is with DbContext, not Code First. DbContext didn’t exist when
>   those assemblies were built, so they don’t understand it.

Resolution is either use **ObjectContext** (*DbConext use ObjectcContext under the cover*)

**[OR]**

Use **March 2011 CTP** that contained fixed-up assemblies (Microsoft.Data.Services.dll and Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll) that know how to work with the DbContext.

Checkout msdn article for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852588.aspx